# How to convert a WSQ fingerprint data to template using MorphoSDK?

Tags: android, kotlin, fingerprint

I want to convert a WSQ fingerprint file into a template file using MorphoSDK. Who else ever came across this situation ?

Comment: You probably have a function for that on the API (there is a long time since I last worked with Morpho SDK). Check the documentation folder on the installation path (you can not publish the documents ok?)

Comment: Hey ! 
Thanks for replying me ! 
I didn't expected to get a response.
Well there is no function doing that in the API.
I've contacted them and they told me that they would forward it to their developers. Actually I can only exportWSQImage but the reverse process is not doable.

I am currently thinking of an image processing algorithm for the matching of a hot captured fingerprint against the saved one.

Comment: That is odd, other vendors have template generating functions, and even matching functions. Unfortunately, I don't have the documentation anymore to check.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time anyway! I appreciate it!